# Loopback access both super model and extended models from same relation

Tags: loopbackjs, extends, relation

I am using Loopback 3 and i have the following three models:
**UserFile.json**

```
{
  "name": "UserFile",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "size": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 0
    },
    "uploadedAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "default": "$now"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "hasFile": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "UploadedFile",
      "foreignKey": "fileId"
    }
  }
}
```

**UploadedFile.json**

```
{
  "name": "UploadedFile",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "hashId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    ......
  },
  "relations": {
    "file": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "UserFile",
      "foreignKey": "fileId"
    }
  }
}
```

**PartitionedFile.json**

```
{
  "name": "PartitionedFile",
  "base": "UploadedFile",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "partSize": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 0
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "file": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "UserFile",
      "foreignKey": "fileId"
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that the **UserFile** has either one **UploadedFile** or (two or more) many **PartitionedFile**.
I want to be able to get from the **UserFile**, from the same relation the file, whether it is an **UploadedFile** or a **PartitionedFile**. Is it possible to achieve this just from the models' definitions or it can only be done with a remote method?

Answer (score 0):

A relation from a model to another is bound to only one model; so you cannot have one relation called "file" to point to different models. In your example, it's bound to `UploadedFile`. In order for your model `UserFile` to have relations with both `UploadedFile` and `PartitionedFile`, you'll need two different relations.

For your UserFile to have either one UploadedFile or many PartitionedFile, it needs to have them both within its relations:

```js
{
  "name": "UserFile",
  ...
  "relations": {
    "uploadedFiles": {
      "type": "hasOne",  // Zero on one uploaded file
      "model": "UploadedFile",
      "foreignKey": "uploadedFileId"
    },
    "partitionedFiles": {
      "type": "hasMany",  // Zero or many partitioned files
      "model": "PartitionedFile"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, to retrieve files from both `UploadedFiles` and `PartitionedFiles` through `UserFile`, you don't need a remote, but to **include** the models within your request.

For example, in ReactJS, it would look like this:

```js
const response = await Axios.get(`/api/UserFile`, {
  params: {
    filter: {
      include: [
        { relation: 'uploadedFiles' },
        { relation: 'partitionedFiles' },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to specify another model `File` that contains all these relations (`UploadedFile`, `PartitionedFile`, etc), so that the model `UserFile` can refer to the table `File` as one unique relation to retrieve the files...